# boilerplate credential code, way to share across stages, steps, jobs?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

Azure Pipelines
PowerShell 5.1

I find myself creating same credential code across stages, jobs and steps. Just wondering if there was a way to reuse?

```
$myPass = '$(myPass)' 
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $myPass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList user1, $securePassword

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $credential {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This command [Get-AutomationPSCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials?tabs=azure-powershell) that uses the **PSCredential** Object to retrieve the data like username, password for reuse.

Sample Code Snippet like:

```
$myCreds = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'credential 
$userName = $myCreds.UserName 
$securePassword = $myCreds.Password 
$password = $myCreds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```